# Try catch inside LINQ loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
var newList = from user in allUsers.ToList()
                       select new
                       {
                           user.FirstName,
                           user.LastName,
                           user.Email,
                           Phone = SomeFunction(user.Data).Phone,
                       };
```

And sometimes the `SomeFunction()` returns a `null` object, then when I try to use .Phone on it, it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Is there a way to catch only that item in the loop and skip it and proceed to the next element instead of skipping on the entire loop?

Comment: One way is to return a special case class for a null item returned from `SomeFunction` that contains the default phone number you would set if there was no phone number to set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign `null`(or a default number) as phone, the [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause in a query is useful to prevent multiple evaluation:

```
var newList = from user in allUsers.ToList()
              let data = SomeFunction(user.Data)
              select new
              {
                  user.FirstName,
                  user.LastName,
                  user.Email,
                  Phone = data == null ? null : data.Phone,
              };
```

Another option is to encapsulate the logic to retrieve the phone from a user in a method. You could even use a real `try/catch` if necessary:

```
private string GetPhone(User user)
{
    if (user == null)
        return null;
    return user.Phone;
}
```

// ...

```
var newList = from user in allUsers.ToList()
              select new
              {
                  user.FirstName,
                  user.LastName,
                  user.Email,
                  Phone = GetPhone(user)
              };
```

Last, with method syntax you could also use a statement lambda where you can use any code you want (at the cost of readability):

```
var newList = allUsers.ToList()
    .Select(user =>
    {
        var data = SomeFunction(user.Data);
        return new
        {
            user.FirstName,
            user.LastName,
            user.Email,
            Phone = data == null ? null : data.Phone
        };
    });
```

Comment: @NadavMiller: note that i've edited my answer to provide alternatives.